# Blender 2.8 Grease Pencil displays [Report ERROR: Nothing to erase or all layers locked] when trying to draw

Tags: error, grease-pencil

I got a graphic tablet and started trying out Grease Pencil, it was working fine, I was enjoying a lot, i switched from DRAW mode to Edit Mode, several times, suddenly while on Draw Mode there was a red dotted circle, I checked online and some people had that problem (they had Guides ON) this is not my problem, it displays REPORT ERROR: Nothing to erase or all layers locked - I have searched everywhere, can't seem to fix it, already downloaded version 2.81, same problem, the layers are not locked, the strange thing is that if I add a Grease Pencil Stroke, then the Red Dotted Circle is able to erase it, also the LINE, Arc and these other tools do work, but not the Draw Tool, which is what I actually need, please any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem on my XPen Deco03.There is a button on my pen Pen/Eraser.
I accidentally pressed it and turned on the Eraser. Just toggle it back to Pen by one more click
[image: How that button looks]

Comment: Wow i cant believe this fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behaviour of an eraser brush. Check if for some reason you have it selected, or try to change your paint brush.

[image]

Comment: It seems like the Draw Tool and the Eraser Tool are behaving like one, I can use the fill tool, and the lower line, arc, square, etc... it's just the Draw Tool that doesn't work, it is behaving the same way as the eraser, I have no idea how this happened, thinking of uninstalling all blender versions, and downloading again... any ideas before doing that?

Comment: thanks for your answer btw

Comment: also just tried File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings, nothing... it just doesn't draw, I'm using a Huion New 1060 Plus graphic Tablet, it works good, I have no idea what is causing Blender not to draw.

Comment: Does it have the same behaviour with a mouse? It could be an error in the interface settings. Also pressing the Ctrl key switches any brush to eraser mode. Hope it can help your troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, simply go to Edit > Preferences > Input > Tablet, and select *Windows Ink* in *Tablet API*

Answer (score 0):

Do these three things:

1. *Edit > Preferences > Enable Emulate 3 Button Mouse*
2. Open the *Pentablet Settings > Restore to Default*, Unplug the cable and plug it in again
3. Set the Pentablet buttons as you want

Try to make a scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the *Nothing to erase or all layers locked* for eraser in Grease Pencil. The mentioned solutions didn't work for me, what did work was this:

1. In the *Outliner*, go to the *Filter* menu
2. Activate *All View Layers*