# Cannot draw with Grease pencil, on tablet or with the mouse, it acts like an eraser

Tags: grease-pencil

SOLVED : so this morning, I started the computer and it worked. That's it!

I cannot draw with the grease pencil tool, it acts like an eraser, although the pencil mode is selected. I found this topic, [Blender 2.8 Grease Pencil displays [Report ERROR: Nothing to erase or all layers locked] when trying to draw](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160731/blender-2-8-grease-pencil-displays-report-error-nothing-to-erase-or-all-layers#), but it did not solve my issue. I tried to change "windows ink" or "automatic" in Edit > Prefs > Input > Tablet API .
When I try to draw with my mouse, it only creates like an "arch", as you can see on the picture. it does not follow the movement of my mouse, it only draws a portion of an arch.
[image]

[image]

I'm using blender 2.9.
Thanks

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of your grease pencil layers, and of the material you are using ?

Comment: Also, you can deselect "Guides" in the top row if you want to stop drawing in arcs : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTSeg.png

Comment: @Gorgious thanks! it solved the issue for the mouse, but not with the stylus, it just erases instead of drawing. I added a picture

Comment: When I start Blender with my mouse, it doesn't recognize the pressure on my stylus afterwards. I have to launch it with the stylus for it to recognize it. Don't know if it is a problem with the OS or with the drivers, or Blender, but it might help if you have trouble again.